# Redirect if no above condition is matched in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am redirecting all the pages of my old domain to a similar page of new  domain and it's working fine but what I also want is that if the user is  trying to access some other page which is not redirecting then it  should automatically redirect to the homepage of the new domain.

Here is part of the file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
Redirect 301 /about-us/ http://www.newdomain.com/about_us 
Redirect 301 /contact-us/ http://www.newdomain.com/contact
```

It's working perfectly but how do I redirect if user tries to access any other page which is not mentioned above? I tried by adding the code below  to the end of the file but it started redirecting every url to the home page

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(about-us|contact-us)/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,NC,R=302] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.newdomain.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Nice  but  actually the list  of  pages (about-us , contact-us) is  more than 200 so i  don't  think  this  code will help me

Comment: You can have individual 301 rules for those 200 pages like `RewriteRule ^foo-bar/ http://www.newdomain.com/foo-bar [L,NC,R=301]` above is just a suggestion

Comment: i didn't understand  what  you mean   i already have  individual rules  for  all  those 200 pages

Comment: Your rules are using `Redirect` directive that should be using `RewriteRule` directive of `mod_rewrite` and last rule must be `RewriteRule . http://www.newdomain.com/ [L,R=302]` to handle all **not mentioned above** pages

Comment: Done  that  but  it's  still redirecting  all  pages  to  the  home  page

Comment: It cannot redirect all pages to home page now. Do you have other rule than these redirects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71349/discussion-between-user2801966-and-anubhava).